# Combox doesnot adding items

Tags: winforms, combobox

When I try to run this program, it shows an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is a print screen

[image]

Comment: It is preferable here on StackOverflow to post the actual source code text that you are having a problem with. Also, adding tags to your question (like which programming language you are writing in) can help your question get looked at by people with that specific knowledge

Comment: This question could definitely be improved to be more clear.  However, a quick look at the screenshot shows that you are trying to access a UI control before the controls have been initialized, which is probably not what you want.  Try ensuring the call to `InitializeComponent()` is called first, and if that does not help, consider editing the question.

Comment: Like Claies said, you probably need to put this `InitializeComponent()` before `comboBox1.Items.Add("...")`

Comment: @Claies, Your good comment can be an answer, then it will be more useful for future readers.

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes, it definitely *could* be an answer.  However, as a rule, I never add an official answer to a question which I feel should be closed.  At the time I added my comment, the screenshot wasn't even visible, and even with the edit that made the screenshot visible, the question still has no code.  My comment was only to give the poster a hint, not endorse the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item you are trying to use (comboBox1) is null because you have not initialized it yet.
On winforms, `InitializeComponent()` will initialize the components you have placed by hand before, with all the attributes needed to correspond the view you have created (position, border, color, etc).

Therefore, `InitializeComponents()` has to be placed before the `comboBox1.Items.Add("Adel")` line. And before any other controls you have not created dynamically.